# Preciso alterar uma coluna do dataframe de acordo com valor encontrado em outra coluna no Python. Como fazer?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Eu preciso que o valor de uma coluna `PERTMINIST` seja alterada a partir de um conjunto de palavras encontrado na coluna `SIGLA`. Por exemplo pode ter na coluna `NOME_ORGAO` as palavras UFJF, UFTM e atualizasse na mesma linha na coluna PERTMINIST com string 'MEC' por exemplo. Como são varias strings possíveis contidas na coluna NOME_ORGAO,  eu pensei em jogar na variável array de string ou conjunto. Segue codigo:

```
conmec = ['UFJF', 'UFTM','MAPA'] 
   for linha in txtosn['SIGLA_ORGAO']:
       if linha in conmec:  txtosn.set_value(linha,'PERTMINIST', 'MEC')
```

[image: Imagem de parte do DataFrame]

OBS: O Codigo acima está colocando os valores corretamente, mas está nan em todas outras colunas da mesma linha onde MEC foi inserido;